# Magento: Paypal returns error

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express

I have integrated PayPal with my website using Magento 1.9.3.4.

I have set-up USD as the base currency and EURO as second currency.

Everything is working fine, but whenever customer place order using paypal, it redirects on paypal's  product=ec&fallback=1&reason=UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY URL after login into the paypal and finally returns error "as this time we are unable to process. please returns to synctechnolab and try another" which is give in below screenshot.

[image]

Could anyone tell on this? I also tried to take help from paypal.

And could you also tell me that Is there alternatives of paypal for individual account in India?